# stick one image over another

Tags: css, image

I have a structure like below:

```css
.a {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  left: 11px;
  top: 89.3px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.a img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.b1 {
  position: absolute;
}
.prev {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/04/10/11752526/gI_134971_best-image-web-hosting.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
  border: medium none !important;
  height: 25px;
  left: -807px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: -220px;
  width: 25px;
}
.prev span {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="a1">
    <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/shasta-daisy-3.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="b1">
      <button class="prev">
        <span>previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="nxt">
        <span>next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is, I need to fixed previous and next button images on my `shasta-daisy-3.jpg` image. For this I used `position: absolute` for my `nxt` and `prev` classes. But when I resized the window, my previous image continously dragged to its left until it disappears, I am unable to stick it to one place over an image

Comment: Can you create js fiddle or pen or Plunker for this?

Comment: Can you give me the link to a jsbin or codepen?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA edited with snippet

Answer (score 0):

You need create wrapper with `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have not given `top` and `left` values to position `.b`, so it doesn't really get absolutly positioned just by saying: `position: absolute`. You have to add: `top:0; left:0` (or right, bottom) so it gets just over your image, like this:

```css
.a {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  left: 11px;
  top: 89.3px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.a img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.b1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.prev {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/04/10/11752526/gI_134971_best-image-web-hosting.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
  border: medium none !important;
  height: 25px;
  left: ;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  width: 25px;
}
.prev span {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="a1">
    <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/shasta-daisy-3.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="b1">
      <button class="prev">
        <span>previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="nxt">
        <span>next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your **CSS**
Here I've created a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/8ydkxd51) and updated your **CSS** slightly as:

```
.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
 .b1 > button {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/04/10/11752526/gI_134971_best-image-web-hosting.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-indent: -999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
.prev {
    left: 0;
}
.nxt {
    right: 0;
}
```

And this will give the output as:

[image]

In this position of next and prev buttons won't change if you resize the browser window. 
Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanku @vivekkupadhy :)

Comment: @nomeer always glad to help :)